Order nested field in an elasticsearch document
I have a document that looks like this
{
    "screeningDate": "2024-06-10T00:02:08+02:00",
    "nbPortfolios": 3,
    "portfolios":
    [
        "item": {
            "code": "foobar"
        },
        {
            "name": "XYZ",
        },
        {
            "name": "123",
        },
        {
            "name": "ABC",
        }
    ]
}

I would like to order alphabetically the portfolios field in my search results in order to have
{
    "screeningDate": "2024-06-10T00:02:08+02:00",
    "nbPortfolios": 3,
    "portfolios":
    [
        {
            "name": "123",
        },
        {
            "name": "ABC",
        },
        {
            "name": "XYZ",
        }
    ]
}

Here is what I tried
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "portfolios.name": {
        "order": "desc",
        "nested": {
          "path": "portfolios"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
…
}

And
…
{
    "nested":
    {
        "path": "portfolios.name",
        "query":
        {
            "bool":
            {
                "must":
                [
                    {
                        "query_string":
                        {
                            "query": "test",
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "inner_hits":
        {
            "sort":
            [
                {
                    "portfolios.name":
                    {
                        "order": "asc"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
…

But the sub documents are not ordered.
EDIT :
Here is what my document actually looks like
{
    "screeningDate": "2024-06-10T00:02:08+02:00",
    "nbPortfolios": 3,
    "portfolios":
    [
        "item": {
            "code": "foobar"
        },
        {
            "name": "XYZ",
        },
        {
            "name": "123",
        },
        {
            "name": "ABC",
        }
    ]
}

And here is the query
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "companyName.sortable": {
        "order": "asc",
        "missing": "_first"
      }
    }
  ],
  "size": 25,
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "query_string": {
                  "query": "537833782*",
                  "default_field": "id",
                  "analyze_wildcard": true,
                  "allow_leading_wildcard": true,
                  "analyzer": "lower_ascii_analyzer"
                }
              },
              {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "portfolios.item",
                  "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "query_string": {
                            "query": "537833782*",
                            "default_field": "portfolios.item.code",
                            "analyze_wildcard": true,
                            "allow_leading_wildcard": true,
                            "analyzer": "lower_ascii_analyzer"
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  "inner_hits": {
                    "sort": {
                      "portfolios.label": {
                        "order": "asc"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}


Please share your mapping

You can use the inner_hits solution for that, but the response a bit different from what you except.
Recommended way:
Sort the data during indexing and just search it.
POST /_bulk?pipeline=sort_portfolios
{"index":{"_index":"portfolios_index","_id":"1"}}
{"screeningDate":"2024-06-10T00:02:08+02:00","nbPortfolios":3,"portfolios":[{"name":"XYZ"},{"name":"123"},{"name":"ABC"}]}

PUT /_ingest/pipeline/sort_portfolios
{
  "processors": [
    {
      "script": {
        "source": """
          if (ctx.portfolios != null) {
            ctx.portfolios.sort((a, b) -> {
              return a.name.compareTo(b.name);
            });
          }
        """
      }
    }
  ]
}

GET portfolios_index/_search


Automation:

To use the ingest pipeline automatically you can put index.default_pipeline settings into index setting.
For existing data use POST portfolios_index/_update_by_query?pipeline=sort_portfolios


Thanks for your anwser. I would like to have the order made at query time. It would prevent me to reindex and it would allow for asc or desc sorting. I can't make the inner_hits query work

For inner_hits implementation, ask chatGPT it will give you the query you need.
Just for clarification, I highly recommend to do that during indexing time. If you need both *asc and desc just copy that nested field and have two nested field for each of them.
It will help to tune the query speed. And you will get rid of a complex task

I understand. So far, chatGPT only gave me false queries that don't work. I'll give it another go. I'll take in consideration your suggestion to do it at indexation time.

Your first attempt (the sort parameter of the query) sorts all hits by a nested field
Your second attempt has error: "path": "portfolios.name" instead of "path": "portfolios".
It works for my mapping and your document
My mapping
PUT /ordered_nested
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "screeningDate": {
                "type": "date"
            },
            "nbPortfolios": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "portfolios": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "name": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Your document
PUT /ordered_nested/_bulk?refresh
{"create":{"_id":1}}
{"screeningDate":"2024-06-10T00:02:08+02:00","nbPortfolios":3,"portfolios":[{"name":"XYZ"},{"name":"123"},{"name":"ABC"}]}

Query
GET /ordered_nested/_search?filter_path=hits.hits.inner_hits.portfolios.hits.hits._source,hits.hits.inner_hits.portfolios.hits.hits.sort
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "portfolios",
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "inner_hits": {
                "sort": {
                    "portfolios.name": {
                        "order": "asc"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Response
{
    "hits" : {
        "hits" : [
            {
                "inner_hits" : {
                    "portfolios" : {
                        "hits" : {
                            "hits" : [
                                {
                                    "_source" : {
                                        "name" : "123"
                                    },
                                    "sort" : [
                                        "123"
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "_source" : {
                                        "name" : "ABC"
                                    },
                                    "sort" : [
                                        "ABC"
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "_source" : {
                                        "name" : "XYZ"
                                    },
                                    "sort" : [
                                        "XYZ"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}


Hello I tried your solution and couldn't get it to work BUT I simplified the query in my SO question. My real case is a little different, and it might be why it doesn't work. I'm actually querying a sub-subfield, but I want to order the subfield. I will edit my question
